# Kafka for real time data processing multiple consumers

Tags: performance, lucene, stream, apache-kafka, message-queue

I am interested in using **Kafka** to stream data (100 K records per second) that has to be consumed by multiple consumers(nosql, lucene) and wanted to know if Kafka is good resource for my requirements or any alternative that are useful as well. The consumers consume data are:

Consumer 1 - consumes data as soon as it comes to topic.
Consumer 2 - consumes data in batches from topic

Comment: Is it possible to read data from live stream in Producer and push to broker?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kafka is a perfect fit for your requirement. Read about Kafka Streams [here](http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html)

If you want to read the data in batches, use the [Kafka Consumer](https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

Comment: Thanks Kamal. I dont' think Kafka streams are suitable for needs and instead thinking of using Producers. How does Kafka streams different from Producers If I need to only send data without any preprocessing to the topic?